# Trying to code a password checker and generator using Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

So far, I have the generator working but I can't get the tkinter to display the variable for the generated password, it only comes up in the console. Once I have the password checker working as well, I need that to be able to change variable as well, please help, here is a copy of my code

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import font as tkfont
import random
import time

global strength
global gen
strength = 0;
gen = '[password will be here]';
global mypw
mypw = '';


def generate():
    alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    pw_length = 8
    mypw = ""

    for i in range(pw_length):
    next_index = random.randrange(len(alphabet))
    mypw = mypw + alphabet[next_index]

    # replace 1 or 2 characters with a number
    for i in range(random.randrange(1,3)):
        replace_index = random.randrange(len(mypw)//2)
        mypw = mypw[0:replace_index] + str(random.randrange(10)) + mypw[replace_index+1:]

    # replace 1 or 2 letters with an uppercase letter
    for i in range(random.randrange(1,3)):
        replace_index = random.randrange(len(mypw)//2,len(mypw))
        mypw = mypw[0:replace_index] + mypw[replace_index].upper() + mypw[replace_index+1:]

    print(mypw)
    gen = mypw;




class SampleApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.title_font = tkfont.Font(family='Helvetica', size=18, weight="bold", slant="italic")

        # the container is where we'll stack a bunch of frames
        # on top of each other, then the one we want visible
        # will be raised above the others
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame

            # put all of the pages in the same location;
            # the one on the top of the stacking order
            # will be the one that is visible.
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("StartPage")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Passowrd program", font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Check your password strength",
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageOne"))
        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Generate a new password",
                        command=lambda:[generate(),time.sleep(0.1),controller.show_frame("PageTwo")])
        button3 = tk.Button(self, text="quit", command=close)

        button1.pack()
        button2.pack()
        button3.pack()


class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label1 = tk.Label(self, text="Check your password", font=controller.title_font)
        label1.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        entry = tk.Entry(self, bd =6)
        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Back",
                       command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))
        label2 = tk.Label(self, text="Strength:", font=controller.title_font)
        label3 = tk.Label(self, text=strength, font=controller.title_font)
        entry.pack()
        button2.pack()
        label2.pack()
        label3.pack()

        password = list(entry.get())


class PageTwo(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        '''while 0 == 0:
            gen = mypw;'''

        var = StringVar()
        var.set(gen)

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label1 = tk.Label(self, text="Generate a password", font=controller.title_font)
        label1.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        label2 = tk.Label(self, textvariable=var, font=controller.title_font)
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Back",
                       command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))
        label2.pack()
        button.pack()



def close():
    messagebox.showinfo("BYE", "Thank you")
    time.sleep(1)
    app.destroy()

#def check_generate():

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()

generate()
```

so, that's my code, I hope someone can help, it would be really useful, thanks

Comment: Hi, which part of your code specifically is not playing nicely?

Comment: It would help if you could reduce your code to a [mcve] that focuses on your problem.

Comment: when I have GUI up, and I click on the 'generate a new password' button, it takes me to the next frame as it should, and says generate a password, then underneath that it says'[password will be here]' instead of the password that is generated and printed into the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you aren't updating the `var` StringVar that is used to display the generated password. Here's a version of your code which fixes that, but it is a little messy. There are a couple of other problems with your code, but I'll let you discover those. ;)

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import font as tkfont
import random
import time

global strength
global gen
strength = 0
gen = '[password will be here]'
global mypw
mypw = ''

def generate(pwvar):
    alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    pw_length = 8
    mypw = ""

    for i in range(pw_length):
        next_index = random.randrange(len(alphabet))
        mypw = mypw + alphabet[next_index]

    # replace 1 or 2 characters with a number
    for i in range(random.randrange(1,3)):
        replace_index = random.randrange(len(mypw)//2)
        mypw = mypw[0:replace_index] + str(random.randrange(10)) + mypw[replace_index+1:]

    # replace 1 or 2 letters with an uppercase letter
    for i in range(random.randrange(1,3)):
        replace_index = random.randrange(len(mypw)//2,len(mypw))
        mypw = mypw[0:replace_index] + mypw[replace_index].upper() + mypw[replace_index+1:]

    print(mypw)
    gen = mypw
    pwvar.set(gen)

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.title_font = tkfont.Font(family='Helvetica', size=18, weight="bold", slant="italic")

        # the container is where we'll stack a bunch of frames
        # on top of each other, then the one we want visible
        # will be raised above the others
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame

            # put all of the pages in the same location;
            # the one on the top of the stacking order
            # will be the one that is visible.
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("StartPage")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Password program", font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Check your password strength",
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageOne"))
        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Generate a new password",
                        command=lambda:[generate(self.controller.frames['PageTwo'].var),time.sleep(0.1),controller.show_frame("PageTwo")])
        button3 = tk.Button(self, text="quit", command=close)

        button1.pack()
        button2.pack()
        button3.pack()

class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label1 = tk.Label(self, text="Check your password", font=controller.title_font)
        label1.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        entry = tk.Entry(self, bd =6)
        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Back",
                       command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))
        label2 = tk.Label(self, text="Strength:", font=controller.title_font)
        label3 = tk.Label(self, text=strength, font=controller.title_font)
        entry.pack()
        button2.pack()
        label2.pack()
        label3.pack()

        password = list(entry.get())

class PageTwo(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        self.var = StringVar()
        self.var.set(gen)

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label1 = tk.Label(self, text="Generate a password", font=controller.title_font)
        label1.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        label2 = tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.var, font=controller.title_font)
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Back",
                       command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))
        label2.pack()
        button.pack()

def close():
    messagebox.showinfo("BYE", "Thank you")
    time.sleep(1)
    app.destroy()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
    generate()
```

---

Here's a slightly better way. Instead of having that dodgy list as the callback function in `PageTwo` we make a proper method, `generate_password`. Not only is it easier to read & to debug, by doing it this way we don't need to pass the password StringVar to `generate`, instead we can get `generate` to return the new password and then set the StringVar inside`generate_password`.

I've also gotten rid of that useless `mypw` global. I removed the messy `from tkinter import *`, and I added the `tkinter.messagebox` so that your `close` function will work.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import font as tkfont
import tkinter.messagebox as messagebox
import random
import time

global strength
global gen
strength = 0
gen = '[password will be here]'

def generate():
    alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    pw_length = 8
    mypw = ""

    for i in range(pw_length):
        next_index = random.randrange(len(alphabet))
        mypw = mypw + alphabet[next_index]

    # replace 1 or 2 characters with a number
    for i in range(random.randrange(1,3)):
        replace_index = random.randrange(len(mypw)//2)
        mypw = mypw[0:replace_index] + str(random.randrange(10)) + mypw[replace_index+1:]

    # replace 1 or 2 letters with an uppercase letter
    for i in range(random.randrange(1,3)):
        replace_index = random.randrange(len(mypw)//2,len(mypw))
        mypw = mypw[0:replace_index] + mypw[replace_index].upper() + mypw[replace_index+1:]

    print(mypw)
    return mypw

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.title_font = tkfont.Font(family='Helvetica', size=18, weight="bold", slant="italic")

        # the container is where we'll stack a bunch of frames
        # on top of each other, then the one we want visible
        # will be raised above the others
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame

            # put all of the pages in the same location;
            # the one on the top of the stacking order
            # will be the one that is visible.
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("StartPage")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Password program", font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Check your password strength",
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageOne"))
        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Generate a new password",
                        command=self.generate_password)
        button3 = tk.Button(self, text="quit", command=close)

        button1.pack()
        button2.pack()
        button3.pack()

    def generate_password(self):
        password = generate()
        password_var = self.controller.frames['PageTwo'].var
        password_var.set(password)
        time.sleep(0.1)
        self.controller.show_frame("PageTwo")

class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label1 = tk.Label(self, text="Check your password", font=controller.title_font)
        label1.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        entry = tk.Entry(self, bd =6)
        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Back",
                       command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))
        label2 = tk.Label(self, text="Strength:", font=controller.title_font)
        label3 = tk.Label(self, text=strength, font=controller.title_font)
        entry.pack()
        button2.pack()
        label2.pack()
        label3.pack()

        password = list(entry.get())

class PageTwo(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        self.var = tk.StringVar()
        self.var.set(gen)

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label1 = tk.Label(self, text="Generate a password", font=controller.title_font)
        label1.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        label2 = tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.var, font=controller.title_font)
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Back",
                       command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))
        label2.pack()
        button.pack()

def close():
    messagebox.showinfo("BYE", "Thank you")
    time.sleep(1)
    app.destroy()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
    generate()
```

Comment: thanks, now I just have to get the check function working (I have it working in a separate file but integration is difficult). You are a life saver

Comment: @J.Walker No worries. Good luck with that. If you run into further problems, you can always ask a new question, but try to reduce the code to the bare minimum that reproduces the problem, as I mentioned earlier. FWIW, I'm not a big fan of the `lambda: [some(), function(), calls()]` pattern. It's easier to read & debug if you write that as a proper method.

Comment: How would I write that as a proper method, I don't like the way it looks but it's the only way that I've found so far?

Comment: @J.Walker Give me a few minutes and I'll add an example to my answer.

Comment: @J.Walker Please see the new improved version. ;)

Comment: thanks, that's even better, because I can recycle that into the checking function as well

Comment: Thanks for all of your help yesterday. I didn't quite get the checking function working the way I wanted to but I found a way around that, so, thank you, you were very helpful.